# How can I preview (watch online) videos while downloading the torrent?

Tags: video, torrents

How can I preview (watch online) videos downloaded from torrent? 

I've tried Torrent Stream Controller with Ace Stream Engine for Android but it seems to be only for torrent tv and I even couldn't force it to work on my device.

Comment: Those two apps have (seemingly) cyrillic descriptions only and the whole service looks illegitimate to me. Can't help you here.

Comment: To the close voters: I fail to see how asking to watch video from torrents while downloading those torrents should be per se illegal. This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequential download feature is more common in current torrent downloading apps, e.g. you may find it in [Flud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delphicoder.flud&hl=en) and [tTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tagsoft.ttorrent.lite&hl=en) apps.

It can be a bit problematic to find video player which supports playback of unfinished video files in various formats. [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc&hl=en) isn't perfect, but quite usable for this.